# backbone can a collection contain model objects of different classes?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am just beginning to use backbone.js for a new crash project. My app has a dynamic (data-driven) user menu. Each menu option is a set of graphs/small tables, of mixed types. For example, a Sales Overview menu option can have a page with 2 pie chart objects, 2 line charts, a bar chart, and so on. I don't know up front what the menu options are going to be, nor what each menu option will entail.

I am considering defining a bunch of generic model "classes" by extending Backbone.Model - PieModel, BarModel, DispersionModel, etc. And corresponding View classes that can render an object of a type - PieView, LineView, and so on. Then I can assemble a page by putting these together as defined by the dynamic configuration. Each model instance's data url can be easily generated on the fly, via the dynamic configuration..

My first concern was if Backbone supports a Collection of mixed Model types. This is instigated by presence of a "model" property for a Collection - does it assume homogeneity?  But it also says a collection can hold an ordered set of models.... model attribute can be polymorphic... a method to get "models" held in the collection. Should I be reading this as "model objects"?

A "page" to me really is a collection of such objects. I would like to create a Collection on the fly and populate it with instances of different model types. And then render this through a View. Or, create a View with an array of various model objects and render the View, bypassing the Collection all together.

I will appreciate your inputs on the design I have outlined, and good reference on backbone, and clarity on how to deploy a Collection in mixed model cases? Perhaps there is a different, smarter way to handle such scenarios...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections only really use their `model` attribute when passing plain objects into its adder functions (e.g. `add`, `push`). If you take a look at [the source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html), each adder function passes the input through `_prepareModel`, which checks if the input is an instance of a `Backbone.Model`. If it's not, it tries to instantiate a new model using the collection's `model`, otherwise it just returns the input untouched.

So as long as you're always adding real Model objects to your collections you should be fine using different types.

However, if you're planning to use aggregate functions that act on model attributes (e.g. `pluck`) you *may* run into errors when the function tries to get at an attribute that doesn't exist in one type of model (though most of the time I think it would just silently fail, which might be what you want).

Comment: Thanks. I'd try using Backbone.Model for model. Since these are mainly visualization widgets there is not much interaction amongst them.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I have 100% properly understood your scenario, however, I am not convinced you are thinking about this in the right way...

In my opinion, your models should contain the *data*, and views should represent them. As such, in a sales context you might have a `SalesData` model which could be displayed in `PieView`, `BarView` or `TableView`. Try to completely separate display logic from data - the type of chart falls under display logic in my opinion.

With the above approach, each page would then contain a set of different views, which you could potentially contain in a master view if you felt the need. Each view would have its own model (or collection depending on how you structure the data), which you can then update/manipulate using the normal Backbone methods.

As far as I know it is not possible for a collection to have different types of models contained within it, but even if it was, I would probably not recommend it as it would complicate the code a lot.

In terms of learning resources, here are a couple:

[Learn Backbone JS compeltely -- javascriptissexy.com](http://javascriptissexy.com/learn-backbone-js-completely/) - this one is very thorough but will take some time to get through.

[Backbone patterns](http://backbone-patterns.heroku.com/) - much quicker to get you in the right frame of mind.

Comment: I agree with you in principle; my app however is different in that rendition is the business end.... +1 for the good links worth exploring.